# REST API: How to name a derived resource?

Tags: api, rest

There is a gazillion of questions about RESTful interface naming conventions, esp. around singular vs plural resource names. A somewhat convention is:

```
GET /users Retrieve collection of users
GET /users/{id} Retrieve user
POST /users Create user
PUT /users/{id} Update user
DELETE /users/{id} Delete user
```

However, the above does not work when resource is a value derived from the environment.

My hypothetical application has the following endpoint:

```
GET /source Get information about the source of the query.
```

That responds with:

- Referrer URL
- Remote IP

Since `source` is derived from the environment, there is never more than one source, therefore calling the resource `sources` or providing `sources/{foo}` lookup is not practical.

Does REST style propose how to handle naming of these entities?

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Fielding notes in section 6.2.1 of his famous [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) :

> ..authors need an identifier that closely matches the semantics they
>   intend by a hypermedia reference, allowing the reference to remain
>   static even though the result of accessing that reference may change
>   over time.

Therefore, it makes sense to use plain `source` endpoint.

It would be a different thing if you wanted to provide more general service around IP address provided, like [this one](http://ipinfo.io/developers).

Comment: Thinking about this further, I've am going to go with a suffix "me" added to the resource name, e.g. https://gist.github.com/gajus/f57136b33ae65ae555f2 This allows future proof design in case "customer" endpoint would allow information about other customers.

Comment: If that's your goal, I'd suggest to keep plural name for that API point and provide simple access to any customer right away via /cusotmers/:id , it will be needed at some point for sure.

Comment: This decision has changed so many times since posting that... I will write a blog post when I am done with this.